# Webservice login without providing an account number..is it possible?

Tags: web-services, soap, netsuite

Is it possible in Netsuite webservice that you will just ask for username and password and after successful validation it will prompt the available accounts associated to that credential?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, it ain't possible using webservices but can be done via REST.

Using the following URL:

https://rest.netsuite.com/rest/roles

..and passing Authorization in the header:

NLAuth nlauth_email=my@email.com, nlauth_signature=mypassword

http://goo.gl/qlEP2

Answer (score 0):

This post contains links to the Netsuite Docs regarding this along with sample code. 
https://dreamxtream.wordpress.com/2012/11/23/new-data-centers-for-netsuite-accounts/